# Double clicking inserts the 'c' character

Tags: notebooks

Sorry for the stupid question but I can't figure out how to stop it and it's caused me a lot of pain. Like the title says when I double click in my notebook with the mouse it inserts the character 'c' where I clicked. Does anyone know why this could be and/or how to stop it?

Comment: What does `CurrentValue /@ {CellEventActions, NotebookEventActions, 
  FrontEndEventActions}` return?

Comment: @Kuba {None, None, None}

Answer (score 2):

I get the 'c' character after almost every click and it has driven me crazy for years and caused me to make countless errors. It is very hard to track down an errant 'c' in a long notebook.

That said, just now I tried an Apple mouse instead of my Microsoft mouse and suddenly I only get an occasional 'c' character. Maybe changing the mouse may help?

FYI. I also have `CurrentValue /@ {CellEventActions, NotebookEventActions, FrontEndEventActions}` equal to `{None, None, None}`.